# How can you determine the timezone offset needed for an arbitrary timezone with respect to daylight savings

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I've seen solutions that make use of the current local timezone. What if I'm looking for the offset of a timezone which is not my own and is currently observing daylight savings time?

Edit:
I realize it is hard to infer exactly what I am asking for.

Currently when a user is set up in the system, they select a timezone. All of our data is converted to this timezone they selected (using the offset).

Example: 
A user selects UTC-8, but then travels to somewhere that is UTC-6. We will display data and convert it based on the UTC-8 offset. The problem here being when daylight savings is applied to this timezone, it is effectively UTC-7. Based on the information available, I am able to get a TimeZoneInfo for UTC-8. I know I can extrapolate from the [TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine if we are currently observing Daylight Savings, and what the delta is. I am curious if there was something in the framework I am missing that would handle this for me before re-inventing the wheel.

Note: This is a web application. The TimeZoneInfo is gathered on the server side, and pass down the User's offset so we can convert UTC to the user's selected timezone preference. I agree it would be easier if the user's browser client provided their system timezone, however it is not viable (due to business rules) to use the timezone of the browser, as the user wants to see the information based on the timezone they have selected.

Comment: Where is this arbitrary time zone coming from? I mean, how do you know it's not "your own"?

Comment: _Ask them to send it to you._ No really, that's how most browser-based applications work!

Comment: @IanMercer - The OP did not imply a browser-based application.  Indeed, it would be helpful to know what kind of application we are talking about here.

Comment: @LukeG - You might just be looking for `TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset`, but note that if you're talking about a web application, you'll need to know the time zone ID of your end user.  Also - lots of questions about this already here on StackOverflow.  Please search before asking.  Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks! This did end up being the key to the problem mixed with creating a new datetime with DateTimeKind.Unspecified. 

var date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

return timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(date);

Comment: You shouldn't do that.  Just pass `DateTime.UtcNow` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the TimeZoneInfo class. I suspect your question is slightly misphrased. The offset is usually part of the name itself and on its own is not usually a very interesting fact. Its usefulness comes from what you then intend to infer from it.

You may be asking:

- Given time X in timezone Y, what time is that in UTC
- Given time X in timezone Y, what time is that in my local timezone
- Given time X in my timezone, what local time will that be in timezone Y

Here is a starter which gives the first:

```
public static DateTime ConvertToUtc(DateTime timeOfInterest, string timezoneId)
{
    TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezoneId);
    if (tz.IsInvalidTime(timeOfInterest))
    {
        // Timezones with DST will be missing (usually) an hour one day a year, so some timeOfInterest
        // values are not valid
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"{timeOfInterest} is not a valid time in {timezoneId} timezone");
    }
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(timeOfInterest, tz);
}
```

You could even do that as an extension method if you wanted.

For those other functions, see also:

- tz.IsDaylightSavingTime()
- tz.GetUtcOffset()
- tz.SupportsDaylightSavingTime
- TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc()
- TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()

Finally, be aware that these rules change all the time as different jurisdictions change their laws regarding the times that they observe. Make sure whatever system is performing these computations gets its windows updates.